# how to make forgot password more secure with JWT token?

Tags: laravel, jwt, token, forgot-password

I am using JWT token for auth in laravel project, and now I am stuck in forgot password. I want to make a token valid for only one click. after user clicked set password on his email he can set his password but another try to set password is impossible. I want to make a user and send him an email with a link to set a password with token on it valid for only one click or something like this.

Comment: you mean, make reset link expire after clicking the link from a mail which will redirect to your password reset page. doesn't matter user successfully updates the password or fail, if he reloads or again visits the same URL then this URL should already be expired since it already been used. Do you want this?

Comment: yes, I want this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, just in-valid token when user reset password successfully. you should delete token after user reset password success

Comment: How to delete that token?
Or just to make a new token and that token automatically is deleted?

Comment: When an user make a request to get a link reset password, you gernerate a token and store it with the email  in a table. The first one click the reset password link and reset password successfullty. You just need delete the record containt the token and email. So the second one will not access to reset password